# PHP site running fine on localhost but not working on a live server

Tags: php, mysql, server, localhost

My PHP site not working on an apache server.It is working fine on localhost but after uploading on the server it showing me the blank pages.Here is my error log file

```
[28-Feb-2018 04:43:16 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Table 'combejcj_waqar-accounts.addsupplier' doesn't exist' in /home/combejcj/waqar.combitpos.com/waqar/public/home.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /home/combejcj/waqar.combitpos.com/waqar/public/home.php(24): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT fullname...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/combejcj/waqar.combitpos.com/waqar/public/home.php on line 24
```

Comment: seems you have not  the table  on the server  ..

Comment: "_Table 'combejcj_waqar-accounts.addsupplier' doesn't exist'_" Did you create your DB and tables?

Comment: have you ever uploaded your Database from localhoat to server ???

Comment: all you need to do is just create the same db on server side and export from localhost and upload it to server

Comment: what's the status of this question? if an answer solved it, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the error message it says that there is no table with the name `combejcj_waqar-accounts.addsupplier`

So, there can be 2 problems:

1) You forgot to upload your DB table

2) You are on a Linux environment which means that you are in a Case sensitive enviroment and in your code you are doing e.g. an insert on `combejcj_waqar-accounts.addsupplier` but the table name is with Capital First letters for example `combejcj_waqar-Accounts.Addsupplier`

So, make sure that the table name on the server is exactly the same with the one you are using into your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what the problem is. It's saying that your MySQL table `combejcj_waqar-accounts.addsupplier` doesn't exist. Did you migrate the MySQL database when you changed over to the server?

Comment: that would have been a fiiiine comment, but not an answer.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not allowed to comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

Table does not exist in the database.
You have 2 possible solutions
 - Export the local database and import it on the live server.
 - Create the table on the live server.